# Removing duplicate integers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

As a beginner python learner I bumped up to a wall at this point and couldn't figure it out.

What I am trying to do is to be able to pick integers in multiple lists and remove the duplicates among them. Then make a copy list which does not include the duplicates.

```python
def my_function(x):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(x))
liss = [[1,2],[3,4,5,6],[1,4,3,99]]
list2 = my_function(str(liss))

list1 = [x for i in list2 for x in i]
print(list1)
```

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with this site's purpose.

Comment: Do not post screen captures of your code. Use your computer mouse to left click somewhere in your code. Press Ctrl-A. Press Ctrl-C. Open up stack overflow. Press Ctrl-V to paste your code into the question. To make your code look pretty (render in a mono-spaced font) put three back ticks above the first line of code, and put three back ticks ``` after your last line of code. The back ticks will tell stack overflow to make your code look like code. all of your code will be indented correctly if you use the back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a set comprehension:

```
>>> xss = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 3, 99]]
>>> xs_no_dups = list({x for xs in xss for x in xs})
>>> xs_no_dups
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write code to implement an algorithm named "***merge-sort***"

You can click on these links to read the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) on [***merge-sort***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Write code to accomplish the following tasks:

1. Sort each list. For example `[4, 2, 1, 2, 5, 0]` becomes `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
2. merge the sorted lists. For example, merge `[1, 3, 4, 9]` and `[2, 6, 20]` to form `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 20]`
3. traverse the final sorted merged list from left to right. If the current element is different from the previous element, then output the current element.

Consider the following list, named `the_list`:

```python
OUTPUTS (VALUES)      [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 14, 14, 14]
 INPUTS (INDICIES)     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
```

Go through the list from left-to-right.

Notice that `the_list[0]` is `1`.
`1` has not been seen before.
So, you should send `1` to the output stream.

We are finished processing `the_list[0]`
Next, take a look at `the_list[1]`.
`the_list[1]` is equal to the previous value.
So, do ***NOT*** send `the_list[1]` to the output stream.

Only when the input changes do we send the input to the output stream.

As long as the input is the same as what it was 2 seconds ago, we send no output to the output stream.

```python
def foobar(the_list):
    # `prev` stands for the English word `previous`

    the_list = iter(the_list)
    prev = next(the_list)    
    yield prev
    for elem in the_list:
        if elem != prev:
            yield elem
        prev = elem
```